# Number of paths on a 6X4 grid

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: 6X4 grid]

How many paths are there from start to end on a 6 × 4 grid as shown in the picture? Note that any such path comprises 6 horizontal unit lengths and 4 vertical unit lengths.

My work: 5^6.                        My logic: There are 5 horizontal rows to which 6 natural numbers need to be allotted.

Answer is something else

why am I wrong

Comment: To be clear... the question author did a very bad job explaining the question.  The fuller question should have been written "*How many paths are there from start to end on a $6\times 4$ grid exist* **where the path can only move up or to the right**"   or equivalently "*How many shortest paths exist from start to finish*" and you can recognize that shortest paths can only use ups and rights.  Your answer of $5^6$ would allow for the path to snake around both up and down as well as rights, but it did not allow for lefts... so even for the extended harder problem you missed some cases.

Comment: Recognize then that for a path from start to finish here to be a shortest path, it must consist of four UP segments, and six RIGHT segments in some order.  There are a total of *ten* segments, we *choose four* of those segments to be ups and that fully describes the overall path.  There are *ten choose four* such paths... $\binom{10}{4}$

Comment: correct answer @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you define the extended harder problem

Comment: How many paths traveling along gridlines exist on an $n\times m$ grid beginning at a point A and ending at a point B such that the path does not reuse any edges but where otherwise *any* direction may be traveled and the path doesn't need to be efficient or shortest?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is just the number of unique permutations of $\{R,R,R,R,R,R,U,U,U,U\}$. There are 10 terms, so it would be $10!$, but 6 of them are the same, so we have to divide by the permutations of the R terms ($6!$), and the other 4 are the same, so we have to divide by the permuations of the U terms too ($4!$).

$$N = \frac{10!}{6!\cdot4!} = \frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1} = 10\cdot3\cdot7 = \boxed{210}$$